# Find dual Euler

Tags: algorithm, graph

Need just some guidance on how to define if graph is dual Euler?
Which mean that there are 2 circuit , if combined to gather we visit all edges in graph.
I can assume that graph contain an Euler circuit.

**EDIT**

### Answer by @ Evgeny Kluev

The graph has 2 Euler cycles if it contains at least one vertex with 4 or more edges.

Comment: The graph has 2 Euler cycles if it contains at least one vertex with 4 or more edges.

Comment: @izomorphius, OP states that "graph contain an Euler circuit". Which I interpret as it is connected.

Comment: @Evgeny Kluev so all i need is to check if i got a vertex with atleast 4 or more edges?
(of course all vertex must have even number of edges else graph wont have Euler cycle).

Comment: @Vlad, yes, that's so simple.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, what do you mean by two Euler cycle? I can't imagine that how we can have two Eulerian cycle in graph?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, I mean exactly what OP requested, two cycles, if combined, giving Euler cycle. As for exact wording, there are two ways to combine these two cycles, which gives two different Euler cycles (sequences of edges in these Euler cycles are not equal to each other).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev, Thanks. so you mean two different cycle by sequence of edges, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is a thesis on [DUAL EULERIAN GRAPHS WITH APPLICATIONS TO VLSI DESIGN](http://www.wpi.edu/Pubs/ETD/Available/etd-0430103-155731/unrestricted/andre.pdf) by Andre Freeman*.

**Euler Circuit\Path:**

- An undirected graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has even degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.
- An undirected graph can be decomposed into edge-disjoint cycles if and only if all of its vertices have even degree. So, a graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if it can be decomposed into edge-disjoint cycles and its nonzero-degree vertices belong to a single connected component.
- An undirected graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if at most two vertices have odd degree, and if all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component.
- A directed graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if every vertex has equal in degree and out degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single strongly connected component. Equivalently, a directed graph has an Eulerian cycle if and only if it can be decomposed into edge-disjoint directed cycles and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single strongly connected component.
- A directed graph has an Eulerian trail if and only if at most one vertex has (out-degree) − (in-degree) = 1, at most one vertex has (in-degree) − (out-degree) = 1, every other vertex has equal in-degree and out-degree, and all of its vertices with nonzero degree belong to a single connected component of the underlying undirected graph.

Source: [Wikipedia:Eulerian Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Properties)

Comment: Fixed, check the provided link to Andre Freeman's thesis on Dual Eulerian Graphs ..